# How to get the Steam Monster mini game started?

Tags: technical-issues, steam-monster-game

With the recent Steam Summer Sale, they introduced a Steam Monster Mini game, where you can level up and get some additional extras in the sale.

Unfortunatelly, it appears that it won't start for me. It doesn't matter whether I join a friend's game or create a new one. The game loads (x/97) and then shows this screen:

[image]

As you can see, it appears to me that the game is loaded, but won't start. There is no object moving, clicking doesn't do anything.

**Is this a known problem and how can I solve it to get the game running?**

Comment: Steam, as one of the biggest gaming platforms, still hasn't sorted their servers out. It's unplayable because of the connection, try it again later. It's worked for me a few times, but only for around 10 seconds until it lost connection again.

Comment: So it's not a problem of mine? (Which I even doubt, as I'm a web programmer and have taken some problem solving.) It's clearly a problem of their overloaded servers? (Which may be true, as Steam servers were crashing often since the Sale started.)

Comment: Nope, problem isn't on our end. Steam has always had problems with their performance (especially) during sales, though I'm surprised it's still this bad over 12 hours after the sale started.

Comment: Steam as well as their servers are currently under big pressure becauss of the big summer sale

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You started the game the way you're supposed to. It is supposed to load up the full thing in the screen you are in.

The reason it doesn't work is on Steam/Valve's end. There currently still are a lot of connection and performance issues because of the high amount of traffic Steam has to deal with during the summer sale.

The game occasionally works but often ends up lagging out and then becomes unplayable. The only thing you can do is wait for the servers to become more stable, and occasionally trying the game again.

Comment: It seems to be working most of the times now, tho still a bit laggy.